# R: filtering columns and creating a new table with the outcome

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I am unfortunately a beginner and would like to ask if any of you have an idea to solve my problem.
It is about a table with club members with the following columns: Name, Address, Postcode, City. Some of these members are married or live at the same address for other reasons. I need to send invitations and those who live at the same address should receive only one common invitation.
I need commands that create a table with the same columns again, but with the names with the same address in a common cell. Is something like this possible? See the picture below for better understanding.

Thank you very much for your help!

[Picture: from how it is now to how it should look like afterwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbUYS.png)

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate with the paste function, roughly:

```
aggregate(df$name, by=list(df$address), FUN=paste)
```